# How to set Recommended(Filterd value) value inside text field in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

[image]

### My code

```
<div id="search-component">  
<input #searchBox id="search-box" (input)="search(searchBox.value)" />
<ul class="search-result">
  <li *ngFor="let result of searchFindLoop" >
    <a>{{result}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

when i will click any recommended value it should set inside text field .How to do it in angular 6.please help me

Comment: `<a (click)="searchBox.value = result">{{result}}</a>`? I'm not sure this is what you're asking, thus posting it in the comment section for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class variable which will contain the selectedResult

```
selectedResult: string
```

Do a one way binding with this variable in your input box

```
<input #searchBox id="search-box" [ngModel]="selectedResult" (input)="search(searchBox.value)" />
```

Set the class variable on selecting any of the results:

```
<a (click)="selectedResult=result">{{result}}</a>
```

**Edit**

You can infact do a two-way binding with the class variable and use that instead of `templateReference`

```
<input id="search-box" [(ngModel)]="selectedResult" (input)="search()" />
```

In your `search()` method, you can directly use the class variable instead of accepting an argument

Answer (score 0):

For these I would recommend to write one simple filter

### SearchPipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe',
})
@Injectable()
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], param: string): any {
    param = param.toLowerCase();

    if (items) {
      return items.filter((item, index) => {
        const find = item.toLowerCase().indexOf(param);
        return find === -1 ? false : true;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

### html

```
<div id="search-component">  
<input #searchBox id="search-box"/>
<ul class="search-result">
  <li *ngFor="let result of searchFindLoop | searchPipe: searchBox.value" >
    <a>{{result}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here are working examples - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-workshop-cc-ng-for-with-filter-pipes-sgljxf

You can modify the codes as per your specific requirement.